# Block the "show" event when my modal is already open (the script reloads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-events

I use a modal to dynamically load content to the user (thanks to AJAX and the link he clicked)

On one of the Ajax pages that I load I added a date field with the bootstrap-datepicker plugin (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**The problem is that when I click on the input to add the date, it is as if the modal is reloading and I cannot block it**

I created a simple example to show the problem (but suddenly on my site, when I click on the date field, it reloads the page at AJAX)

http://jsfiddle.net/1L32hyzt/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="date_from" class="form-control date-test date-from" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var modal = $(this)

  //......

  console.log('MODAL SHOW')
  $('.date-test').datepicker();
  $('.modal-body').prepend('<div><strong>MODAL SHOW</strong></div>')
});
```

**As you can see, when we click on this input, it reloads the script and adds "MODAL SHOW" again**

I tried to add `modal.off();` in the modal script like this:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var modal = $(this)

  //......

  modal.off();
  console.log('MODAL SHOW')
  $('.date-test').datepicker();
  $('.modal-body').prepend('<div><strong>MODAL SHOW</strong></div>')
});
```

But the problem is that if the user closes the modal and clicks on another link, it reloads the same modal as the old one (whereas it is another link with another data)

Where does the problem come from ?

**How to make sure that when I click on the input, the script does not think that I am reloading the modal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code should help with your problem.

```
$(".date-test").datepicker().on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    // prevent datepicker from firing bootstrap modal "show.bs.modal"
    event.stopPropagation();
```

That's a known bug hat has to do with bootstraps datetimepicker
https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/978

Comment: Thank you ! It works ! I also added ``hide.bs.modal`` because I also have a conflict on it